# How is MFC app commiting to virtual memory?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, atlcom

I am working on an MFC app that seems to be automagically committing to ~160MB of virtual memory.  The app typically runs at 10-14MB of memory usage so this level of committed memory seems excessive.  Additionally there is no where in the code where VirtualAlloc is called...
COM & ATL are also being used.

The memory shows as committed the instance the process launches, before a breakpoint in __tmainCRTStartup can be reached.

How can this memory be reserved/committed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there was some "legacy" code using a static array of custom objects that allocated around 1000 extra elements, so changing this to use a std::vector alleviated this issue completely...

Answer (score 0):

The only reason can be a DLL you use. I've used MFC 7.0 and 9.0 for many projects and can tell you that they don't commit this lot of memory.

Comment: Found the issue in some legacy code that had a global stack array of a rather large size, which was committed to and never used unless a page fault occurred.